# Simple Bootstrap Template - Cards Row Issue

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using a simple Bootstrap template from Mobirise for my website and I encountered one issue.
I need to create 5 Bootstrap cards with buttons in a row instead of max 4 available. You can see an example of these cards here: https://mobirise.com/blocks/features-mobirise-4.html

If I just copy and paste the snippet for one card additionally it just displays in the center beneath other 4 cards.

```
<section class="features17 cid-r9nkCuNUpT" id="features17-1">




    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="media-container-row">
            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/01.jpg" alt="Mobirise">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            No Coding
                        </h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            Mobirise is an easy website builder - just drop site elements to your page, add content and style it to look the way you like with simple Bootstrap template.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/02.jpg" alt="Mobirise">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            Simplate Bootstrap Template
                        </h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            All sites you make with Mobirise are mobile-friendly. You don't have to create a special mobile version of your site.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/03.jpg" alt="Mobirise">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            Unique Styles
                        </h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            Mobirise Simple Bootstrap Template offers many site blocks in several themes, and though these blocks are pre-made, they are flexible.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <img src="assets/images/04.jpg" alt="Mobirise">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            Unlimited Sites
                        </h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                           Mobirise gives you the freedom to develop as many websites as you like given the fact that it is a desktop app.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should understand the concept of bootstrap, its row and columns.
globaly, a row is made of max 12 blocks, where each column is defined for example as `col-lg-3` which will occupy 3 blocks (on LarGe screens).
That said, if you need 5 of them, it will be a bit akward, since 12 does not divide with 5. so either 4 or 6, since you already have 4 (`col-lg-3`), you could try 6 `col-lg-2`
refrence: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid always divides the width of the display into 12 columns.
Check out the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for more info.

Let me walk you through the Bootstrap classes:

```
<div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
```

**card** = is a Bootstrap card
**p-3** = padding:3px
**col-12** = mobile-first: this div will occupy all 12 columns on small screens, so just one card per row
**col-md-6** = on medium screens it occupies 6 columns, so you will see two cards next to each other
**col-lg-3** = on large screens it occupies 3 columns = 4 cards in a row

So, if you want to have more than 4 cards on large screens you have to manipulate th col-lg-* class. Because this tells your grid now that no more than 4 elements are allowed per row. In this case I would just go ahead and put 'col' there since 12 is not properly dividable by 5. Then you will have 5 equally-sizes columns.

Like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">col1</div>
  <div class="col">col2</div>
  <div class="col">col3</div>
  <div class="col">col4</div>
  <div class="col">col5</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this.
First is to modify bootstrap core, which is a very bad practice, because in most cases it will bring more problems than it will solve.

Second, and best for you, is to create a wrapper class="col-10 offset-1" which will take 10 columns and center it by 1 column from each side.
for bootstrap 3 is "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"
Than you can set your five elements with a col-2. This way you will have a correct responsiveness and not break anything.